# Is it possible to pass a component as a prop within an object using the spread operator?

Tags: reactjs

Based on the official React documentation, I know that you can pass components as props to other components, in this manner:

```
function SplitPane(props) {
  return (
    <div className="SplitPane">
      <div className="SplitPane-left">
        {props.left}
      </div>
      <div className="SplitPane-right">
        {props.right}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <SplitPane
      left={
        <Contacts />
      }
      right={
        <Chat />
      } />
  );
}
```

My question is, can you pass them within an object, using the spread (...) operator?

Something more like this, based on the above example? I'm just guessing at the syntax here.

```
const splitPaneProps = {
  left: {<Contacts />}
  right: {<Chat />}
}

return (<SplitPane {...splitPaneProps} />);
```

I've searched many combinations of "component", "props", "object" and "spread" with no luck, so this question is a last resort before I assume it's not a thing you can do or I'm really bad at searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just need to change the way you're creating that object:

```
const splitPaneProps = {
  left: <Contacts />,
  right: <Chat />
}
```

Curly brackets are used in the middle of JSX to pop you back into plain javascript, but since you're already in plain javascript, there's no need.

Comment: Thank you. I left Typescript out of my original question to keep it simple. Assuming I'm using TS and want to type the left/right properties, do you have a recommendation? I'm seeing React.ReactNode and JSX.Element as possibilities but I suspect it could be something else and I'm not yet knowledgeable enough about React to pick the correct type.

Comment: Depends how flexible you want `SplitPane` to be. For the SplitPane code you showed, React.ReactNode will work just fine. This will allow passing in elements (`<Contacts />` and `<Chage />` are elements), but also allows anything else that could legally be put inside that div, such as null, fragments (ie, `<></>`), or strings.

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to be stricter and only allow elements. Maybe this is because you're planning to call `cloneElement`, and don't want to have to deal with all other possibilities. Or maybe you just want typescript to give you an error message if you pass in `null` by mistake. For cases like these, JSX.Element (or equivalently, ReactElement) is a good choice.